# Append time dynamically using script manager in vb.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to append time dynamically in vb.net using below code but i always got error "missing ) after argument list" Please  let me know where i am wrong.

```
Dim st As String = "09:00 am"
        Dim ed As String = "11:00 am"

        Dim start As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(st, "hh:mm tt", Nothing)
        Dim [end] As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(ed, "hh:mm tt", Nothing)
        Dim interval As Integer = 30
        Dim lstTimeIntervals As New List(Of String)

        For i As Integer = 1 To 5
            lstTimeIntervals.Add(start.ToString("hh:mm tt"))
            start = start.AddMinutes(interval)


            Response.Write(start + "<br/>")
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "time" + i.ToString, "alert('h');$('.cnt').append(" + start.TimeOfDay.ToString + ");", True)


        Next
```

**ERROR**

$('.cnt').append(**09:30:00**); //here in bold portion of time it is giving error missing ) after argument list
$('.cnt').append(**10:00:00**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the time in quotes:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "time" + i.ToString, "alert('h');$('.cnt').append('" + start.TimeOfDay.ToString + "');", True)
```